# Ignore duplicate key bulk insert with code first EF 6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

I just moved to EF using code first recently. I have 5,000 records to be inserted into a table of 10 million records. I have been having duplicate error flag during bulk insert operation. I have set the Ignore duplicate key flag to yes so as to ignore duplicate key insertion error. However, I do get this error:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

I have achieved the same seamlessly (with ignore duplicate key set to 'yes') without any error flag on ADO.NET using SqlBulkCopy.

My question is how do I do bulk Insert (without iteration nor checking existing records) with ignore duplicate key error flag not being raised using code first. Thanks

Comment: Concurrency is something completely different than Duplicate Keys

Comment: The error occurred after ignore duplicate key has been set to 'yes' in the mssql. What is the best way to handle bulk insert and ignore duplicate error. I don't want iteration or checking for if exists. thanks

Comment: 1. You did not have any duplicate error. You have a concurrency error now. 2. There is an extension method AddOrUpdate 3. EF is not for bulk inserts. If you want bulk inserts then use a sql statement for that